# Android Studio selects wrong target device: always runs app on first selected one

Tags: android-studio

How can I debug other than the first device in Android Studio?

I have two Genymotion devices Nexus 5 and Nexus 6, I can run both successfully but when I try to run/debug app from android studio no matter what device I choose it always runs first selected device.

Initially I thought it is genymotion issue but, it was not the case because same happens if I connect real device. Even though device appears in device chooser dialog but it looks like android studio internally doesn't see it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stopping debugging for current device before selecting new device helped me. (Red square)

[image: Android Studio stop debug]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution
First: Go to run configuration in android studio
Then: Select the emulator you want
Finally: Run it

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Android Studio, supossedly fixed in 1.5.1 but I have 1.5.1 and the bug is still present. Suggested workaround from Google dev is to "close the debug tab once it is done":

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195167